# Maximum call stack size exceeded - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a computed method that allows me to count a total price of my products and discount value and would like to get the value of: total - discount.

```
cartTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    var discount = Math.round((0.1 * this.cartTotal) * 100) / 100;
    this.cart.items.forEach(function(item) {
      total += item.quantity * item.product.price;
    });
    total -= discount;
    return total;
}
```

Doens't work for me and I get that `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

Comment: Are these computed variables?

Comment: You expect `this.discountValue.discount` to call your `discountValue()` method?

Comment: `discountValue.discount` makes no sense (neither does setting `discountActive = true` then immediately throwing it away). What are you trying to do?

Comment: `discountValue()` seems to assume that `cartTotal()` returns a price without the discount subtracted from it, but then in `cartTotal()` you want to subtract the discount from it. There is a logical error here. You must make up your mind: does `cartTotal()` include the discount or not?

Comment: I've got some products that have prices and after typing a correct code to give discount to the price of that product. So I calculate the value of the discount and would like it to be 0,1 of my total price: ` var discount = Math.round((0.1 * this.cartTotal) * 100) / 100` - that's correct. Then would like to subtract that value from my main value `total`.

Comment: The `cartTotal()` doesn't include the discount, but when the user types in a suitable input the correct discount code, I would like to include the discount to the main `cartTotal()`.

Comment: Why `discountValue` needs to be a seperate computed value? You can do what you want in `cartTotal` function only.

Comment: Yeah, you're right but still doesn't work for me :/
 ` cartTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        var discount = Math.round((0.1 * this.cartTotal) * 100) / 100;
        this.cart.items.forEach(function(item) {
          total += item.quantity * item.product.price;
        });
        total -= discount;
        return total;`

Comment: Don't add long code to comments, it's difficult to read, instead, update your question with things you're trying

Comment: Update the question please, and what is the error now? It shouldn't be maximum call stack...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting that error because you have two computed properties that reference each others' value. Whenever you do that, you create a cyclical dependency which will generate a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

You really have three values you're dealing with 1) a sum of all values in the cart, 2) a discount amount, and 3) a total value which is the sum minus the discount.

You should have three computed properties:

```
computed: {
  cartSum() {
    return this.cart.items.reduce((n, i) => n += i.quantity * i.product.price, 0);
  },
  discountValue() {
    return Math.round((0.1 * this.cartSum) * 100) / 100;
  },
  cartTotal() {
    return this.cartSum - this.discountValue;
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, that's what I wanted.