# Vue: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-devtools

This error only occurs when I open Vue.js devtools.

I've seen a few explanations for errors like this, I'm wondering how I can go about finding the location of such culprit within a large code base.

The possible explanations are:

- [Computed properties reference each other, creating a circular dependency.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038871/7933478)
- [Component named same string value as imported component.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526289/7933478)

And here's the error. Again, it only happens after I open Vue.js devtools.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance] (<anonymous>)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2107)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
```

I'm using Chrome 85.0.4183.102 and Vue.js devtools 5.3.3.

Comment: Assuming this is in a git repo that only recently broke, I would crack open `git bisect`

Comment: I've been unable to use vue.js devtools for the better part of a year. I just never got around to trying it again until now.